# Redirect to other folder but get URL appear the same

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting

I have a web app project located in a directory called `issues` with several sub directories.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
-issues
    -applications
    -cli
    -library
    -public
        -css
        -js
        index.php
```

If you point the url to the `issue` folder nothing happens.  To load the website the URL needs to point to `issues/public` and then the site runs from there.

Is there a way to have the url point to just the `issues` directory but load the files as if it was in the `issues/public` directory?

Everything is linked in such a way in the application that it would be impossible to move the contents of the `public` folder to the `issues` folder.

I was looking at htaccess redirects and have so far managed to redirect `issues` to `issues/public` but this isn't ideal.

I did that using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^issues\/?$ "/issues\/public" [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Bit of a side issue, but in internally rewriting to a subfolder, any relative client-side paths _might_ break. (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrites are what you're looking for as long as you don't *redirect* (the `R` flag):

```
# placed under root, ie /.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   # to prevent infinite redirection and 500 error:
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/issues/public 
   RewriteRule ^issues(/?$|/.*$) /issues/public$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Aliases can act—sort of—similarly, but they're not the right tool for the job. They are more comparable to filesystem symlinks than URL-rewriting. Read more from [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096899/216129).

Comment: Will probably need to remove the line-end comment on the `RewriteCond` directive as this is likely to break. (Line-end comments aren't actually supported on Apache. Although they sometimes "work" when there is no ambiguity.) Might also need to make the capturing subpattern on the `RewriteRule` optional if the OP wants to match `/issues`.

Comment: @w3d true. Ironically the line meant to fix a 500 error threw one itself… Missing trailing slashes are usually automatically handled by Apache, if that was what you meant, but I've modified the sub pattern to handle "/issues" request as well.

Answer (score 1):

With a redirect you'll always be redirecting the user to another location, thus changing the url. Therefore you would probably want to use **mod_alias** instead of mod_rewrite.

```
Alias /issues /absolute/filesystem/path/to/issues/public
```